# Trying to create rank-1 SparseArray through LibraryLink causes crash

Tags: bugs, sparse-arrays, librarylink

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.3**

---

When I try to create a 2D SparseArray through LibraryLink's [`MSparseArray_fromExplicitPositions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/ref/callback/MSparseArray_fromExplicitPositions.html), it works fine.  But when I try to create a 1D SparseArray, the program crashes.  Both are illustrated in the program below.

Can anyone see the mistake in my program?

Creating 3D arrays also works as I expect it to, though that example is not included in the question.

---

Mathematica code:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
lib = CreateLibrary[{"sa.c"}, "sa"];

sparseTest = 
  LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "sparseTest", {}, 
   LibraryDataType[SparseArray, Real]];

sparseTest2D = 
  LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "sparseTest2D", {}, 
   LibraryDataType[SparseArray, Real]];
```

This works fine:

```
sparseTest2D[]
```

This crashes:

```
sparseTest[]
```

---

The C code:

```c
#include "WolframLibrary.h"
#include "WolframSparseLibrary.h"


/* Return the version of Library Link */
DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion( ) {
    return WolframLibraryVersion;
}

/* Initialize Library */
DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

/* Uninitialize Library */
DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize(WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return;
}

// THIS FUNCTION CRASHES
// Create a 1D sparse array with 3 explicitly stored elements
DLLEXPORT int sparseTest(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
    int err;
    MSparseArray sa = NULL;

    // 3-by-1 positions array
    MTensor pos = NULL;
    mint posdims[] = {3,1};
    mint *posdata;

    // length-3 values vector
    MTensor vals = NULL;
    mint valsdims[] = {3};
    double *valsdata;

    // length-1 dimensions vector for rank-1 sparse array
    MTensor dims = NULL;
    mint dimsdims[] = {1};
    mint *dimsdata;

    // create positions array
    libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 2, posdims, &pos);
    posdata = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(pos);
    posdata[0] = 1;
    posdata[1] = 3;
    posdata[2] = 4;

    // create values vector
    libData->MTensor_new(MType_Real, 1, valsdims, &vals);
    valsdata = libData->MTensor_getRealData(vals);
    valsdata[0] = 1.5;
    valsdata[1] = 2.6;
    valsdata[2] = 3.7;

    // create dimensions vector, make sure that sparse vector length is larger than highest entry in pos
    libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 1, dimsdims, &dims);
    dimsdata = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(dims);
    dimsdata[0] = 5;

    // THIS CRASHES
    err = libData->sparseLibraryFunctions->MSparseArray_fromExplicitPositions(pos, vals, dims, NULL, &sa);

    libData->MTensor_free(pos);
    libData->MTensor_free(vals);
    libData->MTensor_free(dims);

    if (err)
        return err;

    MArgument_setMSparseArray(Res, sa);

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}


// This function is completley analogous to sparseTest, except that it creates a 2D sparse array instead of a 1D one.
// It does not crash
DLLEXPORT int sparseTest2D(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
    int err;
    MSparseArray sa = NULL;

    MTensor pos = NULL;
    mint posdims[] = {3,2};
    mint *posdata;

    MTensor vals = NULL;
    mint valsdims[] = {3};
    double *valsdata;

    MTensor dims = NULL;
    mint dimsdims[] = {2};
    mint *dimsdata;

    libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 2, posdims, &pos);
    posdata = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(pos);
    posdata[0] = 1; posdata[1] = 1;
    posdata[2] = 3; posdata[3] = 2;
    posdata[4] = 4; posdata[5] = 4;

    libData->MTensor_new(MType_Real, 1, valsdims, &vals);
    valsdata = libData->MTensor_getRealData(vals);
    valsdata[0] = 1.5;
    valsdata[1] = 2.6;
    valsdata[2] = 3.7;

    libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 1, dimsdims, &dims);
    dimsdata = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(dims);
    dimsdata[0] = 5;
    dimsdata[1] = 4;

    err = libData->sparseLibraryFunctions->MSparseArray_fromExplicitPositions(pos, vals, dims, NULL, &sa);

    libData->MTensor_free(pos);
    libData->MTensor_free(vals);
    libData->MTensor_free(dims);

    if (err)
        return err;

    MArgument_setMSparseArray(Res, sa);

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```